# Possible to use a block filter (blocks.getSaveContent.extraProps) with dynamic blocks?

Tags: block-editor

I use a block filter to add classes to core and custom blocks. It doesn't work with dynamic blocks though. I tested with my custom block, and then tried with the core latest posts block and it didn't work either. Is it not possible to use block filters to add classes to dynamic blocks?

I'm using the `blocks.getSaveContent.extraProps` filter, which adds a class to the block on the frontend. My php template for the dynamic block uses this as the outer wrapper, which pulls in alignment and color classes, just not block filter classes:

`<div <?php echo wp_kses_data( get_block_wrapper_attributes() ); ?>> inner block stuff</div>`

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I'm also trying to modify the core/post-template but it does not get called on the hook.

Comment: @GilsonViana Unfortunately, I was not able to solve it. When I do (hopefully), I'll add the solution.

Comment: my workaround solution for this was to wrap my dynamic block with a `core/group` block. I found out that is also possible to modify the core block using the following filter `register_block_type_args`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and stumbled upon this in-depth answer in the closed issue on the Gutenberg repo:

https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/36127#issuecomment-1106645202

I ended up adding the class using the `render_block` filter in PHP, and it is working for me (slightly tweaked from the original example, hopefully for the better):

```
function add_custom_block_class( $block_content, $block ) {
    if ( 
        isset( $block['attrs']['imageHoverEffectEnabled'] ) && 
        $block['attrs']['imageHoverEffectEnabled'] === true 
        ) {
            $injected_class = 'hover-effect-enabled';
            return preg_replace(
                '/' . preg_quote( 'class="', '/' ) . '/',
                'class="' . esc_attr( $injected_class ) . ' ',
                $block_content,
                1
            );
    }else {
        return $block_content;
    }
}
add_filter( 'render_block_core/post-featured-image', 'add_custom_block_class', 10, 2 );
```

Note: I'm using the block specific filter `render_block_core/post-featured-image` instead of `render_block` as this is what I needed in my case.

The `$block['attrs']['imageHoverEffectEnabled']` value comes from a `ToggleControl` component from my custom block.

Hope that helps someone.